# Unidentified Key Chord in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, shortcut

This morning I started working on VS2015 and I notice that the Shift+E key is associated to a Key chord.

I can't use it in the editor or any editing stuff (like rename a file in solution explorer)

I can't identify which command it is associated because it is the first part of a chord and I can find any combination that continues the chord.

I also can't locate any command associated to it in the Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard dialog. The list is huge and I can't search by key.

Please I need help!!! I can't continue to edit the file without using the "E" (uppercase e)

Comment: If you pick any command shortcut key in the Keyboard dialog and try to replace it with shift+E, it shows you the already existing command you are overriding. Don't know if it works with a chord though.

Comment: I confirm that the 3.0.177 version solve this bug.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the problem.

The shortcut reassign was done by the latest update of Powershell Tools for VS2015.

That is a nasty bug.

The command changed was: EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.PowerShell.ExecuteAsScript

It was assigned to "Shift+E, F5" instead of "Shift+Alt+E, F5"

To find out the problem I had to install the Keyboard Shortcut Explorer and export all the shortcuts to xml file an search for the key in Notepad++.

Comment: One thing to note is that EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.PowerShell.ExecuteAsScript show's up in the list twice and it is the second one that is wrong.

Comment: Glad to have found this post.  I end up removing keyboard short altogether and get on with it.

Comment: Yes. Dean that's is correct. I preserved the one with the right key combination but anyway once we got to that point is pretty obvious which one we need to keep. Thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was fixed in version 3.0.177.
Update your Visual Studio extensions or download it from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597

Comment: Thanks for the update john I've just installed the new version. I seems to be OK now.