# Shift-E No Longer Works Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I press Shift-E in Visual Studio 2013 Professional I see on the bottom right (Shift+E) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chard...

All I'm trying to do is type "Export". How can I make this go back to the default behavior?

Comment: The sequence shortcuts should normally react to Ctrl+E, not Shift+E. Check in Tools->Options->General->Keyboard whether the hotkeys have been reassigned.

Comment: I put the cursor in to "Press shortcut keys:" and hit Shift-E and the currently used by remained blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just happened to me as well.. there is another Q with an answer showing the problem.
[Unidentified Key Chord in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924455/unidentified-key-chord-in-vs2015)