# How to trully reset VS2013 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image]

For some reason in my VS2013 environment `shift+E` is assigned to some keyboard command, where additional input is required (see image).

This is extremely frustrating when typing something like:

```
IEvent event = ...
```

Reset procedure through tools->options-> as described here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/05/keyboard-shortcuts-reset-all-your-shortcuts-vstiptool0064.aspx

doesn't seem to work.

Does anybody know how to find and reset this shortcut?

Comment: I don't see an image. Does the status bar at the bottom of Visual Studio say "(Shift+E) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord..."?

Comment: @Lithis: oops my bad, yes it does

Comment: See also [Unidentified Key Chord in VS2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924455/unidentified-key-chord-in-vs2015). Did you recently install or update PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio?

Comment: @Lithis: yes, thats the one: thank you!

Comment: [How do I reset Shift+E behavior in Visual Studio?](http://superuser.com/questions/954944/how-do-i-reset-shifte-behavior-in-visual-studio) also describes how to fix this problem with PowerShell Tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can also reset Visual Studio settings through Tools | Import and Export Settings.... Select "Import selected environment settings" and click Next. Choose whether or not to save your current settings or not and click Next. Select whichever of the default settings you wish to reset your keyboard shortcuts to and click Next. Then uncheck every setting except for Options > Environment > Keyboard and click Finish.

Comment: To bad; this doesn't seem to fix this specific problem. Thanks for the head up though.